# Expand/Collapse one at time

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to expand one element at a time and the others to be closed?
When click open one at a time...

Thanks!

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$(".se-q").click( function () {
  var container = $(this).parents(".se-c");
  var answer = container.find(".se-a");
  var trigger = container.find(".se-t");
  answer.slideToggle(200);
  if (trigger.hasClass("se-o")) {
    trigger.removeClass("se-o");
  }
  else {
    trigger.addClass("se-o");
  }
})
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.not()` , `removeClass()` , `toggleClass();`

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $(".se-q").click( function () {
    var container = $(this).parents(".se-c");
    var answer = container.find(".se-a");
    var trigger = container.find(".se-t");
    answer.slideToggle(200);
    $('.se-t').not(trigger).removeClass('se-o'); // remove the class from all .se-t element but not this one(container.find(".se-t"))
    trigger.toggleClass("se-o"); // toggle class for this(container.find(".se-t"))
  })
});
```

> **Note:** you can catch the point from my code .. but actually you need to provide your html code .. what I got from your code its
>   question/answer script .. so you may need to toggle answer as
>   well

For **answer** you can use the next line before `answer.slideToggle(200);`

```
$('.se-a').not(answer).slideUp(200);
```

Comment: You're welcome @RodrigoBogdanowicz . Have a great day :-)